# Phonegap geolocation is only precise the second time

Tags: cordova, geolocation, location

I'm using the Phonegap GEOLOCATION plugin, which works great but with one annoying issue:
after not using the app for some time, the geolocation result is very general (i.e. city name), only when recalling the function - it becomes correct.

This is how I call the function

```
geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError,{ maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 7000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

I've tried using different timeout values but it made no difference. The first time the function return value is highly inaccurate...

Any ideas how to approach this?